# How to redirect all output of a screen background process in Linux?

Tags: python, linux, process, background, backgroundworker

Trying to find out why a particular process we run with `screen` is not starting.  For this reason, it would be very useful to be able to redirect the output of a screen to a file (like as if using the `>` directive).  Is there a good way to do this?

**The command we run looks like this:**

```
screen -m -d -S some_name_to_reference_it my_program
```

Please note the use -m and -d to daemonize the program and -S to generate a session name.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Excellent.  In the future, whoever voted to close it should vote to move it instead.  Isn't that the way this forum should work?  Thanks!

Comment: @Juan Carlos Coto - I'm actually curious about this. I didn't vote to close the question, but I did click on it to see what happens. It looks like if the "Off Topic" reason is selected, the person can only choose between these alternatives for where it should go: "superuser.com, tex.stackexchange.com, dba.stackexchange,com, and sharepoint.stackexchange.com".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the screen's logging feature. You can invoke this with the -L option.

```
screen -L -m -d -S some_name_to_reference_it my_program
```

This should generate a screenlog file that contains the output.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to redirect stdout and stderr to a log file, have you tried the simple method of using "&>" like this:

```
screen -m -d -S some_name_to_reference_it my_program &> your_log_file.log
```

Hope it helps!